# git Status Shows Files in the New and Modified Section

Tags: git

I've got an interesting occurrence here. I've been developing for awhile (develop on Windows, files get moved to a Linux VM, commits are made from the VM) and have created a number of new files. When I run a `git status`, it shows all my new files in both the `new file:` section and the `modified:` section.

Here's the result of `git status`:

```
# On branch 2.x-merge
# Your branch is ahead of 'composer/2.x-merge' by 1 commit.
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       new file:   SP/ElasticSearch/ElasticSearch.php
#       new file:   SP/ElasticSearch/Filters/AndFilter.php
#       new file:   SP/ElasticSearch/Filters/Boolean.php
#       new file:   SP/ElasticSearch/Filters/OrFilter.php
#       new file:   SP/ElasticSearch/Queries/Boolean.php
#       new file:   SP/ElasticSearch/Queries/Filtered.php
#       new file:   SP/ElasticSearch/Queries/Match.php
#       new file:   SP/ElasticSearch/Queries/MatchAll.php
#       new file:   SP/ElasticSearch/Queries/Term.php
#       new file:   SP/ElasticSearch/esFilter.php
#       new file:   SP/ElasticSearch/esInserter.php
#       new file:   SP/ElasticSearch/esQuery.php
#       new file:   SP/ElasticSearch/esQueryBuilder.php
#       new file:   tests/SP/ElasticSearch/ESTest.php
#       new file:   tests/SP/ElasticSearch/esFilterTest.php
#       new file:   tests/SP/ElasticSearch/esQueryTest.php
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   SP/ElasticSearch/ElasticSearch.php
#       modified:   SP/ElasticSearch/Filters/Boolean.php
#       modified:   SP/ElasticSearch/Filters/OrFilter.php
#       modified:   SP/ElasticSearch/Queries/Boolean.php
#       modified:   SP/ElasticSearch/esFilter.php
#       modified:   SP/ElasticSearch/esQuery.php
#       modified:   SP/ElasticSearch/esQueryBuilder.php
#       modified:   build.xml
#       modified:   tests/SP/ElasticSearch/ESTest.php
#       modified:   tests/SP/ElasticSearch/esQueryTest.php
#
```

If you'll notice, everything that appears in the modified section (except `build.xml`) appears in the new section, and these are all new files so they should.

The commit went fine, I just did a `-am` and there were no issues, I'm just wondering if anyone knows why this happens, what it means, or how it happens.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you changed them since you `git add`ed them?  What are your line ending settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice the headings on the two sections: *Changes to be committed* and *Changes not staged for commit*.

When you use `git add some_file.txt` the current state of the file (in this case `some_file.txt`) is staged to be included in the next commit, so that file will appear in the *Changes to be committed* list. If you make further changes to that file before you run `git commit` those changes won't be staged unless you run `git add` again, so the file will also appear in the *Changes not staged for commit* list.

When you ran `git commit`, you passed the `-a` flag (short for `--all`) which automatically stages all files that have been modified or deleted. This is equivalent to running `git add` on all the files in the *Changes not staged for commit* list before running `git commit`.

Comment: This has to be it. It just makes too much sense for it to be wrong, it seems like the obvious, logical, and ideal behavior too. Perfect answer, everything is crystal clear now. And I learned something about git =D.

Answer (score 0):

Run `git diff` to show the unstaged changes and `git diff --cached` to show the staged changes.

You may have unknowingly changed the line endings in those files. Windows prefers ending lines with 2 bytes (a carriage return and a line feed). Unix prefers ending lines with 1 byte (just a line feed).